# Type Bounds: Apple and Orange

Tags: java, generics, comparator

```
class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {

    private final int weigth;

    public Fruit(int weight) {
        this.weigth = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.weigth, other.weigth);
    }

    public int getWeigth() {
        return this.weigth;
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {

    public Apple(int weight) {
        super(weight);
    }

}

class Orange extends Fruit {

    public Orange(int weight) {
        super(weight);
    }
}
```

The task is to redesign type system and implement right comparison between fruits (apples with apples, oranges with oranges, but not apple with orange and orange with apple).

And "Comparison of Apples with Oranges and Oranges with Apples should be restricted at a compile time".

Don't know how to change it in a right way, please give a hint.

Comment: `Fruit` can't implement `Comparable<Fruit>` any more.

Comment: Why don't you just not implement the interface in the base class?

Comment: I tried to implement it in Apple and Orange classes, but system uses Fruit apple = ..., Fruit orange = ..., and then apple.compareTo(orange);

Comment: "but system uses" isn't preventing that exactly what "Comparison of Apples with Oranges and Oranges with Apples should be restricted at a compile time" means?

Comment: oh, im really stupid, sorry, I thought it means that the error should be in the argument in compareTo function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to introduce an Generic to Fruit which is Representing the "SELF type.."

```
class Fruit<S extends Fruit> implements Comparable<S> {

            private final int weigth;

            public Fruit(int weight) {
                this.weigth = weight;
            }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(S other) {
                return Integer.compare(this.weigth, other.getWeigth());
            }

            public int getWeigth() {
                return this.weigth;
            }
        }

        class Apple extends Fruit<Apple> {

            public Apple(int weight) {
                super(weight);
            }

        }

        class Orange extends Fruit<Orange> {

            public Orange(int weight) {
                super(weight);
            }
        }
    }
```

Prove:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It still compares apples and oranges

Comment: maybe a mistake happend when giving my sample a try?
i just added a screenshot to prove it doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fruit {

private final int weigth;

public Fruit(int weight) {
    this.weigth = weight;
}


public int getWeigth() {
    return this.weigth;
}
```

}

```
class Apple extends Fruit implements Comparable<Apple> {

public Apple(int weight) {
    super(weight);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Apple o){
    return Integer.compare(this.getWeigth(), o.getWeigth());
}
```

}

```
class Orange extends Fruit implements Comparable<Orange>{

public Orange(int weight) {
    super(weight);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Orange o){
    return Integer.compare(this.getWeigth(), o.getWeigth());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If two fruits can't be compared, then why it should be implementing Comparable?
Comparable should be defined at concrete class level, and that way it will solve your problem.

Or if you want to put check in existing class, you can do something like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit other) {
    if(other.getClass().equals(this.getClass())){
        return Integer.compare(this.weigth, other.weigth);
    }
       throw new NotComparableException("Object are of different class, and so can't be compared");
}
```